# markers are not showing on the map

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this codes that gets the lat and lng from the database and show it on google map with markers but it doesn't display any marker.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>Google Maps</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAKcut1aeRFdjPTS5QPefgbrnQIAVkGuis' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        (function(){

            var map,marker,latlng,bounds,infowin;
            /* initial locations for map */
            var _lat=14.676;
            var _lng=121.0437;



            function showMap(){
                /* set the default initial location */
                latlng={ lat: _lat, lng: _lng };

                bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                infowin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                /* invoke the map */
                map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
                   center:latlng,
                   zoom: 10
                });

                /* show the initial marker */
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position:latlng,
                   map: map,
                   title: 'Hello World!'
                });
                bounds.extend( marker.position );


                /* I think you can use the jQuery like this within the showMap function? */
                $.ajax({
                    url: get.php,
                    data: {'ajax':true },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function( data, status ){
                        $.each( data, function( i,item ){
                            /* add a marker for each location in response data */ 
                            addMarker( item.lat, item.lng, item.name );
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                    }
                });                 
            }

            /* simple function just to add a new marker */
            function addMarker(lat,lng,title){
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({/* Cast the returned data as floats using parseFloat() */
                   position:{ lat:parseFloat( lat ), lng:parseFloat( lng ) },
                   map:map,
                   title:title
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(event){
                    infowin.setContent(this.title);
                    infowin.open(map,this);
                    infowin.setPosition(this.position);
                }.bind( marker ));

                bounds.extend( marker.position );
                map.fitBounds( bounds );
            }


            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', showMap, false );
        }());
    </script>
    <style>
        html, html body, #map{ height:100%; width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='map'></div>
</body>
```

This is my get.php the that gets the data from the database.

```
$mysql ="SELECT lat,lng FROM `coordinates`";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $mysql);
if (!empty($result))
{

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $latlng[] = array(
    'lat' => $row['lat'], 
    'lng' => $row['lng'],
    );

  }
 }

  mysqli_close($connect);

 header('Content-Type:application/json');
  echo json_encode($latlng);
 ?>
```

This one is functioning and getting the lat and lng from the database but the markers are still not being displayed in the google maps. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not selecting **"name"** from database but you are using item.name as parameter for **addMarker()** function.

So change your mysql query to:

```
"SELECT lat,lng,name FROM `coordinates`";
```

then add to array:

```
$latlng[] = array(
'lat' => $row['lat'], 
'lng' => $row['lng'],
'name' => $row['name']
);
```

I tried your javascript code and it looks that adding markers works without ajax. Please added JSON string to your question.

If you will have still problems with adding markers with AJAX, you should send JSON (just open **get.php** in browser) and check if you have any errors in developer console - for firefox (CTRL+SHIFT+K).

Comment: It is still not adding markers to the map. Do you think that the problem is in the ajax in the "url"? Is the path correct? My "get.php" is saved/stored online on a free hosting site.

Comment: And also how did it work for you without using ajax? Can I see the codes?

Comment: @Monds The best way how know where is problem is check your get.php file in your browser. You should see JSON string or error. Try open get.php on browser from your adress hosting and send what it writes.

Comment: @Monds I use only your javascript code, nothing more and it is worked good if I replace item.name with "example". So the problem must be in php file or in reading json in javascript. We really need see what get.php writes in your browser. Withou information it is really hard find solution. So just put www.youraddress.com/get.php (or just url to your file) to your browser and see what file returns

Comment: @Monds if you have get.php file on hosting you should have in ajax adress like: http://www.monds.com/get.php or something like that, not only get.php

Comment: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. 

@Bulva Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: Ok, this is mistake in php file. If your php was ok you should see JSON string. Try replace your header in php file with this: header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8'); You probably should add charset definition to your header. Then tell me what page says.

Comment: Thank you @Bulva. I fixed the error on the php file. But it still dont show the marker on the map. Anyway can I get your email? So I can email you because I can't start a discussion to chat because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Hey bro. I want to thank you in person so bad. You're a life saver. Man, I love you so much!

Comment: The problem is i forgot to put '' on the url in the ajax. Thankyousomuch @Bulva!!

Comment: Ok, so it is working now, ye? You helped you alone. I missed " in your put :-)